# Can't find Sublime in Lubuntu 18.10

Tags: lubuntu, sublime-text

According to http://tipsonubuntu.com/2017/05/30/install-sublime-text-3-ubuntu-16-04-official-way/, `apt-get install sublime-text` was the right way to install Sublime.

Unfortunately, I can't find it in Lubuntu 18.10.

```
user@linux:~$ sudo apt show sub
subcommander            subiquity-tools         subread                 substance-flamingo-doc  subtle
subcommander-doc        subliminal              subread-data            substance-swingx        subunit
subdownloader           subliminal-nautilus     substance               substance-swingx-doc    subuser
subiquity               submux-dvd              substance-doc           subtitlecomposer        subversion
subiquitycore           subnetcalc              substance-flamingo      subtitleeditor          subversion-tools
user@linux:~$
```

I've already updated the system (`sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`), but still can't find it. What seems to be the issue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats beacuse sublime-text is not in ubuntu repository as default.
you should fisrt add its repository to your systems repository:
1. install the key:

```
wget -qO - https://download.sublimetext.com/sublimehq-pub.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

2. add its repository:

```
echo "deb https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list
```

Now install it:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text
```